# Is use of generics valid in XCTestCase subclasses?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, xctest

I have a `XCTestCase` subclass that looks something like this. I have removed `setup()` and `tearDown` methods for brevity:

```
class ViewControllerTests <T : UIViewController>: XCTestCase {
    var viewController : T!

    final func loadControllerWithNibName(string:String) {
        viewController  = T(nibName: string, bundle: NSBundle(forClass: ViewControllerTests.self)) 
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            viewController.loadViewIfNeeded()
        } else {
            viewController.view.alpha = 1
        }
    }
}
```

And its subclass that looks something like this :

```
class WelcomeViewControllerTests : ViewControllerTests<WelcomeViewController> {
    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        self.loadControllerWithNibName("welcomeViewController")
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
    }

    func testName() {
       let value =  self.viewController.firstNameTextField.text
        if value == "" {
            XCTFail()
        }
    }
}
```

In theory, this should work as expected -- the compiler doesn't complain about anything. But it's just that when I run the test cases, the `setup()` method doesn't even get called. But, it says the tests have passed when clearly `testName()` method should fail.

Is the use of generics a problem? I can easily think of many non-generic approaches, but I would very much want to write my test cases like this. Is the XCTest's interoperability between Objective-C and Swift the issue here?

Comment: I think you've answered your own question: the setUp and test aren't being invoked. Your idea looks useful. Maybe you could try to implement a pull request: https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-xctest

Comment: Why aren't they getting invoked, is the question. 
In the mean time, I have implemented a very crude way of doing this. Makes my heart churn.

Comment: @avismara What was your solution?  I am using Swift 4 and still cannot run tests when using a generic subclass

Comment: Haven't been able to find one yet. Then again, haven't been actively looking for one either.

Comment: this is pretty messed up.  I'm seeing the same thing--if this isn't permitted, the compile should barf instead of wasting an hour

Answer (score 9):

XCTestCase uses the Objective-C runtime to load test classes and find test methods, etc.

Swift generic classes are not compatible with Objective-C. See https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID53:

> When you create a Swift class that descends from an Objective-C class, the class and its members—properties, methods, subscripts, and initializers—that are compatible with Objective-C are automatically available from Objective-C. This excludes Swift-only features, such as those listed here:
>
> - Generics
>
> ...

*Ergo* your generic XCTestCase subclass can not be used by XCTest.

Comment: This is unfortunate. There should be a compile time error for these kind of framework limitations.

Comment: Sure. But just tell us how on earth could have they guessed this extra-limit use case? Open an radar, and don't take tests and compiler safe-guards for what they are not. Your own skills are still useful.

Comment: Also, now that XCTest is open-source (https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-xctest), you can make a contribution or create an open bug-report at https://bugs.swift.org

Comment: Yes Max. We can expect my answer to become obsolete any time soon.

Answer (score 5):

Well, actually its totally doable. You just have to create a class that will be sort of test runner. For example:

```
class TestRunner: XCTestCase {
    override class func initialize() {
        super.initialize()
        let case = XCTestSuite(forTestCaseClass: ViewControllerTests<WelcomeViewController>.self)
        case.runTest()
    }
}
```

This way you can run all your generic tests.

Comment: No longer workable as of Swift 5 (and probably earlier): `Method 'initialize()' defines Objective-C class method 'initialize', which is not permitted by Swift`.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working in a kind of hacky way with protocols & associated types:

```
import XCTest

// If your xCode doesn't compile on this line, download the lastest toolchain as of 30 november 2018
// or change to where Self: XCTestCase, and do it also in the protocol extension.
protocol MyGenericTestProtocol: XCTestCase {
    associatedtype SomeType

    func testCallRunAllTests()
}

extension MyGenericTestProtocol {
// You are free to use the associated type here in any way you want.
// You can constraint the associated type to be of a specific kind
// and than you can run your generic tests in this protocol extension!
    func startAllTests() {
        for _ in 0...100 {
            testPrintType()
        }
    }

    func testPrintType() {
        print(SomeType.self)
    }
}

class SomeGenericTestInt: XCTestCase, MyGenericTestProtocol {
    typealias SomeType = Int

    func testCallRunAllTests() {
        startAllTests()
    }
}

class SomeGenericTestString: XCTestCase, MyGenericTestProtocol {
    typealias SomeType = String

    func testCallRunAllTests() {
        startAllTests()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39101121/311889) no longer works. The way I did it in Swift 5.2 is:

```
class MyFileTestCase: XCTestCase {
    override func run() {
        let suite = XCTestSuite(forTestCaseClass: FileTestCase<MyFile>.self)
        suite.run()
        super.run()
    }

    // At least one func is needed for `run` to be called
    func testDummy() { }
}
```